# Parsing String in scala to custom case objects

Tags: parsing, scala

Here's something I'm trying to accomplish:

Parsing the following String:

```
"this is plain text, <bold>this is bold</bold>, and <italics>this is italics</italics> etc."
```

The result should be somethings like:

Array(PlainText("this is plain text, "), 
      Bold(this is bold), 
      PlainText(", and "), 
      Italics(this is italics), 
      PlainText(" etc."))

PlainText, Bold and Italics could be case classes.

Any ideas where to start? I've tried to play around regex findAllIn(..), split but
didn't figure this out yet.

Comment: [Arithmetic Expression Grammar and Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805496/arithmetic-expression-grammar-and-parser)

Answer (score 3):

If you can unambiguously define your rules, in BNF, for breaking up the String - then [Scala's parser combinators](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scala+parser) could well be the way forward for you.